# Is it possible to parse a mathematical expression by using #define?

Tags: objective-c, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to make a scientific calculator in which the user enters something like 3+4*(3-5)/2<sup>3</sup> and then the calculator can return the value. 
Now I'm trying to find a way to parse a string of mathematical expression. I know that there are some built parsers and algorithms but I want to know whether it's possible by using `#define` method. 
Basically, I want to use the #define to literally remove the @ and " " in a string and make it look like an expression that can be evaluated. At this stage, I won't use unknown variables like x or 3*k or a*b/c. All will be numbers and operators like 3+4 and 3<sup>2</sup> that can be directly evaluated by the compiler. Here is what I want to write in `#define`:

```
#define eval@"(x)" x
```

In the above code, eval is just a signal of parsing and the @"x" is the actual string that need to parse and x is a mathematical expression. After the translation, only x will remain. For example, if I write

```
double result = eval@"(3+4)";
```

the compiler will read

```
double result = 3+4;
```

(according to my understanding of `#define`). However, the code does not work. I suspect that the quotation marks confuse the compiler and cause the code to break. So my question is: can anyone come up with a solution using `#define`?

Comment: Why would you not just use integer values?

Comment: I want to make a scientific calculator in which the expression is entered by the user (and recognized by the compiler with scanf or button pressed).

Comment: Then it definitely can't be done with preprocessor macros if it is dependent on dynamic input.  Anything done with the preprocessor has to be known and evaluatable at compile-time.  What you need is a string parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#define` is an invocation of the C preprocessor, which is not capable of this kind of manipulation. It almost sounds like you're trying to define an Objective-C macro that would do the same kind of thing as a LISP macro, but that's not possible. Why don't you tell us [what the original problem is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that you're trying to solve... I think we can probably come up with an easier way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Basically, I want to make a scientific calculator that can do a series of calculator upon pressed enter (including deciding precedence of operations all on its own).

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to write a calculator, but you're trying to offload all of the actual parsing and calculation to the Objective-C parser and compiler. If you want to accept input from the user then you're going to have to parse and interpret the expressions yourself.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible with the preprocessor, no string manipulation besides concatenation supported.

Why would you need the @"x" syntax anyways? You can just put the expression right there in the code.

Comment: If I want to write codes for a calculator in which the user can put a string of numbers and operations (like a scientific calculator, not a simple one like 3 + 4 enter and then display 7), then I think the input must be in the form of a string. Am I right?

Comment: The preprocessor only runs on your own computer, when the code is compiling. It won't work during runtime to parse expressions for you. You need to either write a simple parser yourself or find a library that does it for you.

Answer (score 2):

People are right, you cannot do it in direct way, however if you very want macro:

```
#define eval(x) [[[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:x] expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil] doubleValue]

double result = eval(@"3+4");
```

Comment: If you're going to take this approach there's no reason to keep using `#define`.